# What does grow up as calves in the stall mean in Malachi 4:2b?

Tags: malachi

Please explain what does *grow up as calves in the stall* mean as stated in Malachi 4:2?

> *and ye shall go forth, and grow up as calves of the stall.* - [Malachi 4:2b](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Malachi%204:2&version=KJV)

Answer (score 4):

The complete verse is:

> But unto you that fear my name shall the Sun of righteousness arise with healing in his wings; ***and ye shall go forth, and grow up as calves of the stall.***. - [Malachi 4:2](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Malachi%204:2&version=KJV)

I think that it means **happiness** and **victory**. For the calves who stay in stall is a real happiness when they go out and see the sunshine.

Analogous, for the people of God - *who fear [God's] name* - is a great  happiness when *the sun of righteousness shall rise* and the *healing in its wings*.

The first verse from the chapter says:

> For, behold, the day cometh, that shall burn as an oven; and all the proud, yea, and all that do wickedly, shall be stubble: and the day that cometh shall **burn them up**, saith the Lord of hosts, that it shall leave them neither **root** nor **branch**. - [Malachi 4:1](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Malachi%204:1&version=KJV)

We have here the scene of the final abolishment of the sin, of the sinners (*branch*) and of the Sattan (*root*).

The fire will clean up the Earth of any trace of the sin and the God's kingdom will be instaured on the New Earth. The saints will celebrate the **victory** of God and the war between God and Satan that will be finally finished.

Comment: Can you explain your reasoning for the passage? Thanks.

Comment: @Anonymous It's a comparison between the people of God  that are saved from the sin and the *calves of the stall*.

Answer (score 2):

- President Joseph Fielding Smith (1876–1972) taught that children who will be raised during the Millennium “shall grow up ‘as calves of the stall’ unto righteousness, that is, without sin or the temptations which are so prevalent today” (The Way to Perfection [1970], 299).
- Contemplate the difference between a calf that is raised out on the range or in the mountains and one that is raised in a barn. The calf on the range is subject to all the forces of nature: inclement weather, predatory animals, and occasional scarcity of food and water. On the other hand, the calf raised in the barn or in a stall is protected from poor weather and predatory animals. Likewise, food and water are regularly provided. Nephi taught that “the time cometh speedily that the righteous must be led up as calves of the stall” (1 Nephi 22:24).

One commentator said: “Those who are left after the judgment of the Second Coming will be able to raise up their children as calves are raised in a stall. The calf is protected from the elements, and his environment is controlled (Malachi 4:2; 1 Nephi 22:24). The children in the Millennium will similarly ‘grow up without sin unto salvation’ (D&C 45:58). The telestial element will be removed, and with Satan being bound (Revelation 20:1–3; 1 Nephi 22:26; D&C 101:28), the environment will be more controlled” (Monte S. Nyman and Farres H. Nyman, The Words of the Twelve Prophets: Messages to the Latter-day Saints [1990], 145).

Comment: There is some useful logic here but you really need to [join the dots](http://meta.hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/533/43) a bit more - it reads like a list of unconnected quotes or facts.

Answer (score 1):

Calves of the stall are terms used when referring to a position often taken by animal like cow when they relax to rest and you can't push them. So message In Malachi 4:2b is that by reason of God's salvation that will come anyone who fears and honour Him "nothing can kill, destroy or move such a person". It mean no evil program will reach you.

Answer (score 0):

calves released from the stall… in Jewish tradition, the Calves were sustenance for the lives of the people but also given as offerings. Looking at Romans 12 in the New Covenant passages it talks about being a living sacrifice. This passage I thought reflects this, as the healing comes, we are set free from our bondage and released to "frolic" under the grace and love of HaShem.

Comment: Hi, user3247. Although I cannot say much about the validity of your answer, I would like to make a comment that you may be better off with some sources or references. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

But unto you that fear my name (God), shall the son of righteousness (Jesus Christ) arise with healing in his wings... and ye shall go forth and grow up like calves in the stall.

> **John 1:12** But as many as receive him (fear his name) to them he gave the power to become the sons of God (calves in the stall)...

We are always learning, even as old, experienced, adults, we need to be as little children, ever learning and receiving understanding to become more like God. As we have faith in Jesus Christ, be patient in our trials and afflictions and continually humble learners, our faith will be made whole and bring peace and protection as a stall would to a calve in a stall as we continue to grow our understanding.

> **Mosiah 23:27** But Alma went forth and stood among them, exhorted them that they should not be frightened, but that they should remember the Lord their God and he would deliver them.
>
> **Alma 36:3** ...for I do know that whosoever shall put their trust in God shall be supported in their trials, and their troubles, and their afflictions, and shall be lifted up at the last day.
>
> **Alma 36:27** And I have been supported in my trials and troubles of every kind, yea, and in all manner of afflictions; yea, God has delivered me from prison, and from bonds, and from death; yea, and I do put my trust in him, and he will still deliver me.

Answer (score 0):

Calves of the stall are raised to follow those who raise them. They are kept safe by obedience. This is opposed to the wild cattle, who are free roaming and not in the safe confines of the stall, or in the safety of the calves' owners (The Lord).

Comment: Welcome to Bible Hermeneutics SE and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/653/how-can-we-educate-new-users-about-our-site-distinctives/803#803).